# ¿Cómo extraer las imágenes de un PDF con mi programa en C?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que me abra el archivo PDF que desee y a continuación extraiga las imágenes que contenga para abrirlas después con OpenCV

Este es mi código para abrir el archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué función tengo que usar para extraerle las imágenes y que se guarden en una carpeta?

Answer (score 0):

Te contesto vía respuesta porque no me entra como un comenario.

`ShellExecute` es una función de la API de Windows que en este caso es equivalente a abrir el fichero mediante doble click... no puedes interactuar con el fichero abierto ya que no lo está abriendo tu programa sino el visor de PDF que tengas instalado.

Para manipular el PDF tienes dos opciones:

- Te empollas el estándar de PDF y creas una librería capaz de acceder al contenido que quieres dentro del PDF.
- Buscas alguna librería de terceros que sea capaz de entender PDF. En este caso te toca estudiar su API para recuperar la información que buscas.

Como ves ninguna de las dos respuestas va a ser concreta y concisa. Yo en tu lugar optaría por ir un poco más despacio y aprender primero la base del lenguaje. Salta a la vista que tu nivel no es el suficiente para entender lo que tienes que hacer y el proyecto que pretendes te puede acabar metiendo en un laberinto sin salida con extrema facilidad.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Seguiré tu consejo